# Installing IPython master JS dependencies on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipython

While I see others on S.O. with similar issues, I don't seem to get the solutions to work?

I was having issues with NB convert, in IPython 1.0, (which was running fine elsewise) I figured I'd just install master so I ran the following on Ubuntu 12.10

```
sudo pip install https://github.com/ipython/ipython/tarball/master
```

which appeared successful
but when starting the notebook I got a blank page on the browser with this isn the console:

```
WARNING:root:404 GET /static/components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css (127.0.0.1) 0.34ms
WARNING:root:404 GET /static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js (127.0.0.1) 0.19ms
WARNING:root:404 GET /static/components/bootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js (127.0.0.1) 0.30ms
WARNING:root:404 GET /static/components/requirejs/require.js (127.0.0.1) 0.55ms
WARNING:root:404 GET /static/components/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js (127.0.0.1) 0.41ms
WARNING:root:404 GET /static/components/requirejs/require.js (127.0.0.1) 0.29ms
WARNING:root:404 GET /static/components/bootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js (127.0.0.1) 0.37ms
WARNING:root:404 GET /static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js (127.0.0.1) 0.36ms
WARNING:root:404 GET /static/components/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js (127.0.0.1) 0.36ms
WARNING:root:404 GET /static/components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css (127.0.0.1) 0.29ms
WARNING:root:404 GET /static/components/requirejs/require.js (127.0.0.1) 0.26ms
WARNING:root:404 GET /static/components/bootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js (127.0.0.1) 0.28ms
WARNING:root:404 GET /static/components/requirejs/require.js (127.0.0.1) 0.44ms
WARNING:root:404 GET /static/components/bootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js (127.0.0.1) 0.39ms
```

So I need to install the dependencies, I'm not so swooft with pip so can someone tell me where to go to run the right commands?

I see the docs that say that I need to update and suggest pip install -e .[notebook] but I don't think I am executing that in the right spot? I cannot find where PIP put the base install? So I don't see the basic setup.py files? Or do I need to create a local IPython Git repo? If so some guidance?

```
tom@tom-sam:~$ sudo pip install -e .[notebook]
Directory '.' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.  
Storing complete log in /home/tom/.pip/pip.log
```

I'm dead in the water at the moment so help much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPython cannot be installed from github tarballs.

Comment: so, next suggestion?? where to from here now that I may have borked stuff? Actually It appears to be running except for the JS ???

Comment: Ok, I seem to have fixed it by cloning the Git repo and installing from there, thanks

Comment: simplest way to install IPython from GitHub: `pip install -e git+https://github.com/ipython/ipython.git#egg=ipython[notebook]`